# Primefaces IE9 X-UA-COMPATIBLE

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, tomcat6

I m using primefaces 5.1 with spring 4 and all work like a charm on firefox, but my client want that PF works on IE9, and when i test some page, i see that render are different, and after a google search, i find this :

```
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> 
</f:facet>
```

and miracle all work fine!

well almost...

All pages are ok but when i go back under eclipse console i see many errors!!! like :

```
INFO: Server startup in 3280 ms 
10 avr. 2015 09:27:59 com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ATTENTION: JSF1064 : Impossible de localiser ou de servir une ressource, theme.css, depuis la bibliothèque primefaces-aristo.
10 avr. 2015 09:27:59 com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ATTENTION: 
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363)
...
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset by peer: socket write error
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketOutputStream.socketWrite(SocketOutputStream.java:92)
...
10 avr. 2015 09:27:59 com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ATTENTION: JSF1064 : Impossible de localiser ou de servir une ressource, primefaces.css, depuis la bibliothèque primefaces.
10 avr. 2015 09:27:59 com.sun.faces.application.resource.ResourceHandlerImpl logMissingResource
ATTENTION: 
ClientAbortException:  java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
at org.apache.catalina.connector.OutputBuffer.realWriteBytes(OutputBuffer.java:369)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.flushBuffer(ByteChunk.java:448)
at org.apache.tomcat.util.buf.ByteChunk.append(ByteChunk.java:363)
...
```

i see that primefaces-aristo theme is default theme and present into primefaces-5.1.jar so its not a classpath problem because other css / js are ok

my header :

```
<f:facet name="first">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=9" /> 
</f:facet>
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery.js" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="jquery/jquery-plugins.js" />
<h:outputScript library="primefaces" name="primefaces.js" />
<h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces" name="primefaces.css"/>
<h:outputStylesheet library="primefaces" name="jquery/ui/jquery-ui.css"/>
```

so if it was resources not found problem, i should see it in firefox too? and in IE9 the page is correctly showed, so i don t understand clearly this error.

**Environnement**

```
-primefaces 5.1
-jsf 2.2.9
-spring 4.1.4
-el-impl 2.2
-jsp-api 2.1.3-b03
-jsf-api 2.2.9
-jsf-impl 2.2.9
-el-api 2.1.2-b05
 tomcat 6
```

any help will be appreciate :)

Comment: Why are you outputting jquery and PrimeFaces CSS? PrimeFaces does this automatically.

Comment: yes your are right, i try it for a test to force including but now i have remove them all and i have always the same error in eclipse console log :(

Comment: Offtopic: Jsf 2.2.9 and jsf-api 2.1.7 is a wrong combination.

Comment: yes your are right @kukeltje, i made a mistake is should be jsp-api-2.1.3-b03 and not jsf! i have jsp-api 2.2.9 too, i update my topid

Comment: Now you make the reverse mistake in the comment ;-)

Comment: yes i m doing too many things at same time ;) but you understand, and if you have a solution to my problem, you're welcome :D thanks ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you first open a page in IE, it immediately starts loading resources. Then IE considers switching to compatibility mode. If it does decide to do that, then it aborts all the resource requests and starts them anew. That's why you see those log messages. They're not important in this case, pages will work fine.

You could just tell to IE to disable compatibility mode completely, and always use the actual version by setting the `X-UA-Compatible` header to `IE=edge`. Then it won't abort requests anymore.

Comment: thanks for your reply, i have test this but i always have this message in my console, i use IE9.0.8112 because the client using this version and dont want to uprgrade all computers, so i m stuck with this version :( here is the source at the begenning :<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"><head>
     <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" /><link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/castorsurveillance-web/javax.faces.resource/theme.css.jsf?ln=primefaces-aristo" /> ... but problem doesn't disappear sorry

Comment: @MançauxPierre-Alexandre, I don't think there is a need to upgrade IE. When I discovered this, I set the `X-UA-Compatible` as a response header instead of a meta tag. I doubt this makes a difference, but it's worth a try. Are you sure the messages you saw in the console were related to this? E.g. if you press F5 before the page finishes loading, that means aborting requests too. Or maybe your IE is set to override to a certain compatibility level? With IE dev tools you can override the `X-UA-Compatible` suggestion.

Comment: hello, i don t know why, but today its working, i have no error message in my console :) thanks to you for your help